# JavaScript ajax post not getting data in python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I am beginner in web developing. I am trying to make the ajax request with POST method (without jquery). Following is my JS code

```
function loadDoc() {

  var Obj = {"user_Name":"testName"};

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("x").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/Messapp/hostelapp.py", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");


  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(Obj));
}
```

Then following is my python script

```
#!D:/python/python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/json\n\n")

import cgi, cgitb , re 
cgitb.enable() 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() #I am facing problem in this line 
print(form["user_Name])
```

Please see the below error
[image: Error image]

Comment: Why without jQuery?

Comment: Why are you setting the content-type to json, but then sending something that is clearly not JSON?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Post edited. Actually I have sent the JSON data, But I have tried with some other example that code I have posted. Can you tell me what is the issue in my request.

Comment: @roganjosh I am learning JavaScript that the reason I am trying with pure JS. Can you tell we can not achieve with JS.?

Comment: I cannot tell you either way if it can or cannot be achieved, but I was curious about why it was a requirement. Fair enough if it's for learning purposes.

Comment: Ok but now the backend isn't expecting JSON. Why are you using JSON at all?

Comment: Actually I don't know what kind Header I have to pass. First I have tried with the form method `<form action="/cgi-bin/Messapp/hostelapp.py" method="post">` it works the same method I have trying with the ajax.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the following header in the ajax, instead of the json

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```